# How to use Facebook API's "folder" and "tag" parameters when reading a page's mailbox?

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to read my test page's mailbox using the [/conversations edge](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/conversations/).

What I want is getting conversations related to a specific folder but whenever I try something like `/page-id/conversations?folders=done` I get the same results as `/page-id/conversations`. The same goes whenever I try the 'tags' parameter.

And once I move a conversation to another folder like the 'done' using 
the Facebook website, it disappears from the results of `/page-id/conversations`

Anyways, besides the 'folder' thing, is there a way to get a conversation's "label" and "notes" specified by the page's admin?

And it seems that the messages' tags are not affected by the folder they reside in. So even after I move a conversation to the "done" folder, its messages still have the "inbox" tag associated with them. Am I missing something obvious here?

P.S. Solution suggested at [How to query conversations by folder via Graph Api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47686033/how-to-query-conversations-by-folder-via-graph-api) didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close to solution. Instead of folders=done, try folder=page_done with Page access token.

```
{page-id}/conversations?folder=page_done
```